# Creating HTML links from images in :colons: with Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I have a simple HTML document:

```html
<div should-not-be-replaced=":smile:">
  Hello :smile:!
</div>
```

How would I replace the `:smile:` text with `<img src="smile.png">`, but keeping the first `:smile:` unchanged, to get this:

```html
<div should-not-be-replaced=":smile:">
  Hello <img src="smile.png">!
</div>
```

---

I tried this, but Nokogiri escapes my HTML as plain text:

```ruby
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html)
doc.traverse do |x|
  next unless x.text?
  x.content = x.text.gsub(':smile:', '<img src="smile.png">')
end
```

Comment: Don't use `traverse` for this. Use selectors and one of the many methods in Nokogiri to locate the specific nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is very similar to Ku's, although I've tried to handle situations where the replaced text could be in the source text multiple times by completely replacing the content text with an HTML Doc Fragment

```rb
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(DATA.read)
doc.traverse do |x|
  next unless x.text?
  if x.text.match(%r{:(\w+):})
    replace_text = x.text.gsub(%r{:(\w+):}, "<img src='#{$1}.png'>")
    x.content = ""
    x.add_next_sibling replace_text
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Please see my comment on Ku's answer regarding the problem with `add_next_sibling` append the image tags at the end of the text instead of replacing it in their correct place.

Comment: using `add_next_sibling` in this case doesn't effect the positioning of the replaced text because I've used your original regex to completely replace the entire content text.

Comment: I see, that's great! Thank you!

Comment: using `add_next_sibling` is simply  short cut to get nokogiri to correctly parse the new img tags within the content text

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you want, and it also deals with strings between two colons like :something: and produces "something.png" as well.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html)
doc.traverse do |x|
  if x.text? && x.content =~ /:\w+:/
    x.content = x.content.sub(/:(\w+):/, '')
    a = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse('<a src="'+$1+'.png">')
    x.add_next_sibling(a)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that the new `<img>` tag is always added to the end of the text. So these two strings `Hello :smile:` and `:smile: Hello` will both be replaced with `Hello <img src="...">`

Answer (score 0):

You are making it much too hard, and using `traverse` which is slow because it forces Nokogiri to walk through every node in the document; In a large page that is costly.

Instead take advantage of selectors to find the specific node(s) you want:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div parm=":smile:">
  Hello :smile:!
</div>
EOT

div = doc.at('div[parm=":smile:"]') 
div.inner_html = div.text.sub(/:smile:/, '<img src="smile.png">')
puts doc.to_html
```

Running that results in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<div parm=":smile:">
  Hello <img src="smile.png">!
</div>
</body></html>
```

I'm using `at`, which finds the first occurrence. If you need to process more than one then use `search`. `search` returns a NodeSet, which is like an array so you'll want to iterate over it. That are innumerable examples of doing so on Stack Overflow and elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks! The `:smile:` in the attribute value was added as an example to demonstrate that attribute values should be untouched.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean it returns `&lt` or `&gt`?

I recommend to wrap `CGI#unescape_html` method

try,

```
require 'cgi'
CGI::unescape_html(doc.to_s)
```

Comment: Nokogiri itself can manage this without needing to use CGI. I'd recommend researching how.